# Error "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" arising

Tags: errors

Sorry if it's a duplicate question. I'm relatively new in LaTex, and I'm in a self-learning procedure with the help of internet. 
Now in my code, the error showing is, **Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 63--65**

Line **62** from Line **66** of the code is below;

```
L62: \begin{adjustwidth}{0.21in}{}
L63: $\#$ Prove that the set \ $S = \{x: x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i x^i, \ \lambda \geqq 0, \ i = 1, 2, \cdots , m$ \ and \ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i = 1 \}$ \ is a convex set.\\
L64: \hspace*{0.14in}\textbf{Proof}: Let \ $\bar x, \hat{x} \in S \subseteq \mathbb{R} ^ n$ \ and \ $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ \ such that \ $0 \leqq \lambda \leqq 1$. Let \ $x$ be a point in \ $\mathbb{R}^n$ \ such that \\
L65: \begin{adjustwidth}{0.4in}{}
L66: \vspace{-0.17in}
```

I saw more than 6 tex-stack questions and tried to solve my problems, yet can't deal with these. Can anyone please show me the road to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

PS: If my question is a duplicate one, or my question is solved in some other question, then please do lead me there. (Though getting answer here would help me in a great manner.)

Comment: Do not end lines using `\\ `. From the code fragment you showd, it is not entirely clear what kind of output you want to achieve. Could you add a description/sketch?

Comment: Have you checked if this question has been asked before? A quick serarch lists plenty of answered questions related to "underfull \hbox badness 1000"https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Underfull+%5Chbox+%28badness+10000%29+in+paragraph

Comment: Generally, manual instructions such as `\hspace*{0.14in}` and `\vspace{-0.17in}` should rarely be needed. Please also explain what you wanted to  achieve with `\begin{adjustwidth}{0.21in}{}` followed by another `\begin{adjustwidth}{0.4in}{}`.

Comment: @leandriis, See [link](https://bit.ly/3bIFbCt) for visual description. Line 63 starts from `#Prove.... ` and the very next line ends. I hope you'll understand.

Comment: @user1729210 I mentioned that before PS. Sorry for not searching the whole bunch. Actually you see, I use a "limited" data connection pack. So it's difficult for me to browse every link. That's why I posted. Now if there is direct answer to my question in some previous questions, then please do lead me there. Sorry again for my internet related problem here.